# $n$ boxes with $i-1$ red balls and $n-i$ yellow balls

Tags: probability

We have $n$ numbered boxes from $1$ to $n$. Box $i$ contains $i-1$ red balls and $n-i$ yellow balls. We randomly chose a box and we draw two balls without substitution.

1. Find the probability that the second ball is yellow.

Let $X_i$ be the event that we pick the box $i$. Thus

$\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(g_2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(g_2,X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(X_i)\mathbb{P}(g_2|X_i)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-i}{n-1}$

2. Find the probability that the second ball is yellow if the first is yellow.

$\rightarrow \mathbb{P}[(g_2|g_1)|X_i]=\frac{\mathbb{P}(g_1|X_i)\mathbb{P}[(g_1|g_2)|X_i]}{\mathbb{P}[g_2|X_i]}=\frac{\frac{n-i}{n-1}\cdot \frac{n-i-1}{n-2}}{\frac{n-i}{n-1}}=\frac{n-i-1}{n-2}$

$\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(g_2|g_1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(X_i)\mathbb{P}[(g_2|g_1)|X_i]=\frac{n-i-1}{n(n-2)}$

3. Find the probability to draw the box 1, knowing that the two balls are both yellow.

$\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X_i|g_1,g_2)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_i)\mathbb{P}(g_1|X_i)\mathbb{P}(g_2|X_i)}{\mathbb{P}(g_1,g_2)}$ where

$\mathbb{P}(g_1,g_2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(g_1,g_2,X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(X_i)\mathbb{P}(g_1,g_2|X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(X_i)\mathbb{P}(g_1|X_i)\mathbb{P}(g_2|X_i)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n-i}{n-1}\cdot \frac{n-i-1}{n-2}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-i}{n-1}\cdot \frac{n-i-1}{n-2}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n-i}{n-1}\cdot \frac{n-i-1}{n-2}}$

---

Is it correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can the answers possibly involve $i$?  $i$ is a variable, not a known number.  It makes sense that the answers involve $n$, which is some fixed number, but not $i$.

Comment: @saulspatz Great, I didn't understand anything.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be closed, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer is not quite correct. Let $X_i$ be the event that you pick box $i$. In your first answer, you found $\mathbb{P}(g_2 | X_i)$. We have $\mathbb{P}(g_2) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{P}(g_2 \cap X_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{P}(X_i)\mathbb{P}(g_2 | X_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{n - i}{n(n - 1)}$.

In the second answer, we have $\mathbb{P}[(g_2 | g_1) | X_i] = \frac{n - i - 1}{n - 2}$. Then $\mathbb{P}[g_2|g_2] = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{P}[X_i]\mathbb{P}[(g_2|g_1)|X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n-i-1}{n(n-2)}$.

For the third answer, we have $\mathbb{P}[X_1 | g_1 \cap g_2] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[X_1]\mathbb{P}[g_1 \cap g_2 | X_1]}{\mathbb{P}[g_1 \cap g_2]}$. We can easily compute $\mathbb{P}[X_1]$ and $\mathbb{P}[g_1 \cap g_2 | X_1]$. To compute $\mathbb{P}[g_1 \cap g_2]$, we take the same approach as before, knowing that $\mathbb{P}[g_1 \cap g_2] = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{P}[X_i]\mathbb{P}[g_1 \cap g_2 | X_i]$.

Now for the questions you posed. Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be the events that the numbers drawn in the first and second draw match respectively.

For the first question, note that it does not matter what ball you drew from $A$. You only need the ball you drew from $B$ to match it. Thus, the probability they match is $\mathbb{P}[M_1] = \frac{1}{n}$.

For the second question, suppose that the two numbers matched during the first draw (recall this occurs with probability $\frac{1}{n}$). We have the same scenario as in the first question but with $n-1$ distinct numbers instead of $n$. The probability in this case is $\mathbb{P}[M_2 \cap M_1] = \mathbb{P}[M_1] \cdot \mathbb{P}[M_2 | M_1] = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n-1}$. If the two numbers did not match during the first draw (which occurs with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$), then we have the exact same scenario as in the first question for the second draw. The probability in this case is $\mathbb{P}[M_2 \cap M_1^c] = \mathbb{P}[M_1^c] \cdot \mathbb{P}[M_2 | M_1^c] = \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$. The total probability is thus $\mathbb{P}[M_2] = \mathbb{P}[M_2 \cap M_1] + \mathbb{P}[M_2 \cap M_1^c] = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{n - 1}{n}\right)$.

For the third question, we have $\mathbb{P}[M_1 | M_2] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[M_1]\mathbb{P}[M_2|M_1]}{\mathbb{P}[M_2]} = \frac{\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n - 1}}{\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{n - 1}{n}\right)} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{(n-1)^2}{n}} = \frac{n}{(n-1)^2 + n}$.